# IBOutlet UILabel do not get resized

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder, uilabel

HI all,

I have designed a view in Interface Builder and connected correctly with its controller.
There some UILabel in it that are going to be filled with lot of text.
But, even if I have declared "word wrap" and set line to 0 in IB, I can display only first line. I notice that if I increase the height of the UILabel in IB, all the text display properly in multi line, but I cannot do that because text may vary.

Shouldn't the UILabel resize itself to fit all the text ?
Also, if I built the UILabel programmatically I can succesfully accomplish a word wrap, why cannot do the same with IB ?

What am I doing wrong ?

thanks
Leonardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to call sizeToFit programmatically on UILabel.
I wonder if there's a setting in IB to emulate this command.